# Is it possible to integrate $\int_1^{\infty}{\frac{x}{x^2-e^{-x}}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I know that I can use the comparison test to determine that the integral diverges from 1 to infinity. But is there a way to actually integrate this function?

$$\int_1^{\infty}{\frac{x}{x^2-e^{-x}}dx}$$

Comment: I realize now the title looks funny, I don't know what I was thinking. But I hope the actual question makes sense.

Comment: Is it supposed to be $e^{-2}$, which is just a constant? If it's just $x^2$ minus a constant in the denominator then this question is significantly easier than I'd a have first expected.

Comment: Make the change of variable $u = x^{2} - e^{-2}$.

Comment: If you're aware that the integral diverge, what are you expecting when you say "actually integrate this function"? Are you asking for an antiderivative of $\frac{x}{x^2-e^{-2}}$?

Comment: Átila Correia gives the most direct route for this specific integral.  More generally for these types of integrals, look into _partial fraction decomposition_

Comment: @Chessanator you're right, it's supposed to be ^(-x), that's my bad. I've changed it now.

Comment: @jjagmath The original question was asking to determine whether the integral diverges or converges. I know a comparison test can be used to find that it diverges, I was just wondering if it was also possible to integrate the function.

Comment: [I don't think it's possible to find an antiderivative.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+x%2F%28x%5E2-e%5E%28-x%29%29)

Answer (score 0):

The given integral does not converge.

However, if the problem was
$$\int_1^\infty \left(\frac{x}{x^2-e^{-x}}-\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx$$ it would rletively simple since
$$\frac{x}{x^2-e^{-x}}-\frac{1}{x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n x} x^{-(2 n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty E_{2 n+1}(n)$$ where appears the exponential integral function.

The summation would converge quite fast to $0.138465$ since
$$\frac{E_{2 n+3}(n+1)}{E_{2 n+1}(n)}\sim \frac 4{11} \frac{n}{n+1}$$